# Access VBA: enter expression in user form, store calculated result in table?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, user-input, ms-access-2010

I've got a form that I'd like users to be able to enter simple maths into, with the calculated value stored in the table.

For example:

1. User enters "1+5" into a text box.
2. The answer 6 is stored in the database table.

Currently, entering "1+5" in my numeric form field results in an error re: 'entering text into a numeric field'. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a VBA script to parse the input and perform any needed calculations. This could be triggered by an unbound form field's BeforeUpdate event.

Steps:

1. Create a field named Field1 for the calculated value (bound to the appropriate database field).
2. Add an *unbound* field to your form and name it Input1.
3. In Design view, right-click on Input1 and choose Properties. Under Events -> Before Update, click the "..." button.
4. Insert the VBA code that I have written (below).
5. Save your changes and close the VBA editor.
6. Return to Form view and enter an expression into your Input1 field. When you tab out of the field, the expression will be evaluated and the value will appear in Field1.

*Note that, for reasons of security and/or data integrity, you may need to sanitize your user input before evaluating it as an expression. The details of "how" and "why" fall outside the scope of the original question.*

```
Private Sub Input1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  ' TO-DO: Validate/sanitize input as necessary for security & validity;
  '        Exit Sub prior to the Eval() if we see something we don't like
  Dim result As Variant
  result = Eval(Input1.Value)                ' Evaluate the contents of Input1
  If IsNumeric(result) Then Field1 = result  ' Save any numeric result to Field1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, any tips on parsing it ?  I've tried eval() and things like cdbl().  i.e. me.mytotal = eval(me.mytotal)

Comment: Thanks very much.  Your solution works, if I use a separate field, but I was hoping to do it in the same field (lots of data input fields, so doubling the numbers is not preferred).

Comment: You can make this solution behave exactly as though it is in the same field. Simply right-click Input1 and Layout->Remove. Right-click Input1 again and Position -> Bring to Front. Move Input1 so that it is exactly on top of Field1. Right-click Input1 and choose Properties. On Input1's Format tab, set Back Style to Transparent. On Input1's Events tab, click the "..." button for the "Lost Focus" event and add one line to Sub Input1_LostFocus: **Input1 = Null**. Save your changes in the VBA editor. Finally, on **Field1**'s Data tab, set Enabled to No and Locked to Yes. Save the form and test.

Comment: Thanks Miles.  Nice solution, but way too much effort, too many fields and all probably will have input like that, I think I'll covert application to excel and add the basic data functions I need, rather than using proper database.